# Spring 4 - Object won't autowire variable

Tags: java, junit, autowired, spring-4

I have my junit testing class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppConfig.class })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TelephoneNumberTest {

@Autowired //Test that bean exists in application context
private void setPhoneNumberValidator(PhoneNumberValidator phoneNumberValidator){
    this.phoneNumberValidator = phoneNumberValidator;
}

@Test
public void autoWireValidatorTest(){
    assertNotNull(phoneNumberValidator); //Test passes

}

@Test
public void validUSNumber(){
    PhoneNumber phoneNumber = null;
    ContactType expectedContactType = ContactType.PRIMARY;
    Country expectedCountry = Country.UNITED_STATES;
    String expectedAreaCode = "940";
    String expectedExchangeCode = "368";
    String expectedLocalNumber = "7410";

    try {
        phoneNumber = new TelephoneNumber(expectedContactType, expectedCountry, expectedAreaCode,
                expectedExchangeCode, expectedLocalNumber);
    } catch (InvalidPhoneNumberException e) {
        fail(e.getMessage());
    }

    assertNotNull(phoneNumber);
    assertThat(phoneNumber.getContactType(), is(expectedContactType));
    assertThat(phoneNumber.getCountry(), is(expectedCountry));
    assertThat(phoneNumber.getAreaCode(), is(expectedAreaCode));
    assertThat(phoneNumber.getExchangeCode(), is(expectedExchangeCode));
    assertThat(phoneNumber.getLocalNumber(), is(expectedLocalNumber));
}
}
```

My AppConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("software.userprofile")
public class AppConfig {}
```

My PhoneNumber object

```
package software.userprofile.models;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import software.userprofile.models.exceptions.InvalidPhoneNumberException;
import software.userprofile.models.validators.*;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class TelephoneNumber implements PhoneNumber{
private ContactType contactType;
private Country country;
private String areaCode;
private String exchangeCode;
private String localNumber;
private PhoneNumberValidator phoneNumberValidator;

public TelephoneNumber() {}

public TelephoneNumber(ContactType contactType, Country country, String areaCode, String exchangeCode, String localNumber) throws InvalidPhoneNumberException {
    this.contactType = contactType;
    this.country = country;
    this.areaCode = areaCode;
    this.exchangeCode = exchangeCode;
    this.localNumber = localNumber;
    validate();
}

public ContactType getType() {
    return contactType;
}

public Country getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public String getAreaCode() {
    return areaCode;
}

public String getExchangeCode(){return exchangeCode;}

public String getLocalNumber() {
    return localNumber;
}

public PhoneNumberValidator getPhoneNumberValidator(){
    return phoneNumberValidator;
}

@Autowired
private void setPhoneNumberValidator(PhoneNumberValidator phoneNumberValidator){
    this.phoneNumberValidator = phoneNumberValidator;
}

public void validate() throws InvalidPhoneNumberException {
    phoneNumberValidator.doValidation(country, this);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TelephoneNumber{" +
            "contactType=" + contactType +
            ", country='" + country + '\'' +
            ", areaCode='" + areaCode + '\'' +
            ", exchangeCode='" + exchangeCode + '\'' +
            ", localNumber='" + localNumber + '\'' +
            '}';
}

public static Comparator<TelephoneNumber> COMPARE_BY_TYPE = new Comparator<TelephoneNumber>() {
    public int compare(TelephoneNumber one, TelephoneNumber other) {
        return one.getType().compareTo(other.getType());
    }
};
}
```

and lastly my PhoneNumberValidator class

```
package software.userprofile.models.validators;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import software.userprofile.models.Country;
import software.userprofile.models.PhoneNumber;
import software.userprofile.models.exceptions.InvalidPhoneNumberException;

import java.util.*;

@Component
public class PhoneNumberValidator {
private Map<Country, PhoneNumberCountryValidator> phoneNumberValidators = new HashMap<Country, PhoneNumberCountryValidator>();
private Country defaultCountry;

public PhoneNumberValidator(){
    init();
}

private void init(){
    phoneNumberValidators.put(Country.UNITED_STATES, new USPhoneNumberCountryValidator());
    phoneNumberValidators.put(Country.UNITED_KINGDOM, new UKPhoneNumberValidator());
    phoneNumberValidators.put(Country.MEXICO, new MexicoPhoneNumberCountryValidator());
    phoneNumberValidators.put(Country.CANADA, new CanadaPhoneNumberValidator());
}

public void doValidation(Country country, PhoneNumber phoneNumber) throws InvalidPhoneNumberException {
    if(country == null){throw new InvalidPhoneNumberException("Country code is null");}
    phoneNumberValidators.get(country).validate(phoneNumber);

}

public void setPhoneNumberValidators(Map<Country, PhoneNumberCountryValidator> phoneNumberValidators) {
    this.phoneNumberValidators = phoneNumberValidators;
}
```

}

My issue: The PhoneNumberValidator object in the TelephoneNumberClass isn't autowiring and when I run the test I'm getting a null pointer exception in the doValidation() instance of PhoneNumberValidator. The only thing I can think of is that the TelephoneNumber class isn't being recognized by spring, but I don't know how to fix that.

I've looked at several post on the site, but nothing has worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Class `TelephoneNumber` is not managed by spring, you need to inform spring to manage it as a bean. E.g.

```
@Component
public class TelephoneNumber implements PhoneNumber {...}
```

Comment: I just tried that but no luck :(, I'm getting the same error

Comment: In your test class you are not injecting spring bean rather creating an instance of `PhoneNumber` manually like this  `phoneNumber = new TelephoneNumber` , Hence just call `phoneNumber.setPhoneNumberValidator` or inject the `phoneNumber` bean

Answer (score 1):

You are creating TelephoneNumber with **new**. You should get it from the applicationContext (as *prototype* so it always returns a new one). Or if you need to use new, then you can enable Spring aspects and an agent.